# Bloom filters for determining which sets in a family are subsets of a given set

Tags: algorithm, hash, bloom-filter

I am trying to use a Bloom filter to determine which sets from a family of sets `A1`, `A2`,...,`Am` are subsets of another fixed set `Q`. I am hoping that someone can verify the correctness of the stated approach or offer any improvements.

Let `Q` be a given set of integers, containing anywhere from 1-10000 elements from the universe set `U = {1,2,...,10000}`.

Also, let there be a family of sets `A1`, `A2`,...,`Am` each containing anywhere from 1-3 elements from the same universe set `U`. The size `m` is on the order of 5000.

*outline of algorithm:*

Let there be a collection of `k` hash functions. For each element of `Q` apply the hash functions and add it to a bitset of size `n`, denoted `Q_b`.

Also, for each of the `Ai`, `i = 1,...,m` sets, apply the hash functions to each element of `Ai`, generating the bitset (also of size `n`), denoted `Ai_b`.

To check if `Ai` is a subset of `Q`, perform a logical AND on the two bitsets, `Q_b & Ai_b`, and check if it is equal to the bitset `Ai_b`. That is, if `Q_b & Ai_b == Ai_b` is false, then we know that `Ai` is not a subset of `Q`; if it is true, then we do not know for sure (possibility of a false positive) and we need to check the given `Ai` using a deterministic approach.

The hope is that the filter tells us the majority of the `Ai`'s that are not in `Q` and we can check the ones that return true more carefully.

**Is this a good approach for my problem?**

(Side questions: How big should `n` be?  What are some good hash functions to use?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the range of values is rather small (as in your example), you can use a simple deterministic solution with linear time complexity.

1. Let's create an array `was` (with indices from 1 to 10000, that is, one cell for each element of the universal set), initially filled with `false` values.
2. For each element `q` of `Q`, we set `was[q] = true`.
3. Now we iterate over all sets of the family. For each set `A_i`, we iterate over all elements `x` of the set and check if `was[x]` is true. If it's not for at least one `x`, then `A_i` is not a subset of `Q`. Otherwise, it is.

This solution is clearly correct as it checks if one set is a subset of the other by definition. It's also rather simple and deterministic. The only potential downside it has is that it requires an auxiliary array of 10000 elements, but it looks admissible for most practical purposes (a bloom filter would require some extra space too, anyway).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. For my problem, it is usual that there are only a few `Ai`'s that are actually in `Q` (on the order of 10-30), would this make a bloom filter more desirable or would the deterministic approach you described above still perform better?

Comment: @jobnem If there are no problems with deterministic approach, I'd still use it. It has another advantage: it's simple.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to ask only one question in your question.

I will address the first one: "Is this a good approach for my problem?", but not the last two, "How big should n be? What are some good hash functions to use?"

This is probably not a good approach.

First, `Q` is tiny; 10,000 elements from `{1,...,10k}` means `Q` can be stored with a bitset in 10k bits or about 1.2 kibibytes. That is very, very small. For instance, it is smaller than your question, which uses almost 1.5 kibibytes.

Second, `Ai` contains one to three elements, so `Ai_b` will likely be larger than `Ai` unless you chose them to be so small that the false positive rate is very high.

Finally, hash function computation is not free.

You can do this much more simply if you check each element of each `Ai` against a bitset representing `Q`.